# Only output specific Values using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to work out how the SQL if I want to bring back ALL "Names" from table1 and only list the output in Column 2 to contain the value if it is "Apple".  If its not "Apple" or is "Null" then column 2 should also be "Null"

Table 1

| **ID(pk)** | **Name** |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | Boris |
| 25 | Dominic |
| 26 | Rishi |
| 27 | Elizabeth |
| 28 | Ben |

Table 2

| **ID(fk)** | **Description** |
| --- | --- |
| 27 | Apple |
| 27 | Orange |
| 27 | Pear |
| 26 | Apple |
| 26 | Pear |
| 25 | Pear |
| 24 | Orange |

Required Output

| **Name** | **Description** |
| --- | --- |
| Boris |  |
| Dominic |  |
| Rishi | Apple |
| Elizabeth | Apple |
| Sajid |  |

Comment: Can there be duplicate rows in the second table? For example, can there be multiple rows with the same (27, 'Apple') values?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. The answer is 'No'. There will only be one type of fruit per ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no duplicates in the second table (in a comment below the question you confirmed that this is the case), this is a simple application of outer join.

Here I include the test data in the `with` clause. You don't need it - you have the actual tables. Remove the `with` clause, and inspect the main query and change the table and column names as needed.

```
with
  table_1 (id, name) as (
    select 24, 'Boris'     from dual union all
    select 25, 'Dominic'   from dual union all
    select 26, 'Rishi'     from dual union all
    select 27, 'Elizabeth' from dual union all
    select 28, 'Ben'       from dual
  )
, table_2 (id, description) as (
    select 27, 'Apple'  from dual union all
    select 27, 'Orange' from dual union all
    select 27, 'Pear'   from dual union all
    select 26, 'Apple'  from dual union all
    select 26, 'Pear'   from dual union all
    select 25, 'Pear'   from dual union all
    select 24, 'Orange' from dual
  )
select t1.name, t2.description
from   table_1 t1 left outer join table_2 t2 
                  on t2.id = t1.id and t2.description = 'Apple'
order  by t1.id
;


NAME      DESCRIPTION
--------- -----------
Boris           
Dominic         
Rishi     Apple 
Elizabeth Apple 
Ben
```

Comment: Hi - thanks very much for this which worked!!  Its extremely frustrating as I had previously tried this but had put the "t2.description = 'Apple'" bit in a where clause.  I'm quite new to this so I need to go away and understand why it works differently as per your solution.  Thanks very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in a variety of ways, one example:

```
SELECT t1.name
     , MAX(CASE t2.descripton WHEN 'Apple' THEN t2.descripton END)
FROM t1
JOIN t2
    USING(id)
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

The CASE expression will map all but Apple to null. MAX will then reduce the set to either Apple or null for each name.

Comment: This will output three rows for Elizabeth, not just one.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I overlooked that. So much easier if there is something useful in the question to test with. I'll modify my answer

Comment: Hi - thanks for taking time out to help.  The statement wouldn't work as given above USING(id), but worked once id put the correct syntax in and added an outer join.

Comment: It is standard SQL, but you can replace it with ON t1.id=t2.id if your DBMS does not support it

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will work for you:

```
Select Name, CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table2 WHERE LOWER(description) = 'apple') THEN 'Apple' ELSE Null END as Description FROM table1;
```

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: I have left the office for the day. I can check this first thing tomorrow morning and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no worries

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your solution which I tested and worked.  The only issue was it ran a little slower than the other solution provided.  Thanks for taking the time out to help :)